# Modify database table based on a change in an ordered list

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

this issue has been plaguing me for over a week now and I am in desperate need of a solution.

I have been building a module for our ColdFusion based CMS system which allows users to build a course which has a sequence of classes. The sequence order represents prerequisites, so for instance:

Class 1
Class 2
Class 3
Class 4

Class 1 is the first class in the sequence and is needed in order to proceed to class 2, etc...

I have successfully allowed users to create said courses however editing them is the trick. In my editing interface the sequence is represented in a CFSELECT listbox. The user is able to perform 4 actions on the list: Move up, move down, delete, and add. This gives the user the ability to fully manipulate the list.

The Problem:

Our database is really old, in fact our whole CMS system was built in '99 so were dealing with a fairly out of date and somewhat poorly designed dataset. The sequence is stored as follows:

Each course is stored in a table called moodle_programs. Its unique identifier is the column mpID which is an auto increment.

Each class in the sequence is stored in a table called moodle_course, its unique identifier is mcID which is an auto increment.

We store the relationships in a lookup table called moodle_relationships which has the following structure:

- mrID - auto increment
- mpID - the course ID
- mcID - the class ID
- active - Y/N
- predecessor - The first row in the sequence is set to 0, the rest to the mrID of the previous row

A row in moodle_relationships represents one class in the sequence.

This means that my algorithm basically needs to consider the following:

If the current class list = the current number of rows for that course
    Then overwrite mcID with the correct values
Else IF the current class list is < the current number of rows for that course
    Then overwrite mcID until the end of the sequence is reached, and set all remaining rows to active='N'

This is accomplished by this algorithm:

```
//comma deliminated list of mcIds before edit
<CFSET preclasses = listToArray(#PREsectionOrder#, ",")>
// number of classes 
<CFSET numpreClasses = ArrayLen(#preclasses#)> 

//comma deliminated list of mcIds after edit
<CFSET classes = listToArray(#sectionOrder#, ",")>
//number of classes 
<CFSET numClasses = ArrayLen(#classes#)>

<!--- Modify moodle_relationships --->
<CFQUERY NAME="Course_seq" DATASOURCE="#CMS_SD#">
SELECT *
    FROM moodle_relationships
    WHERE mpID = #URL.id# 
</CFQUERY>

<CFSET row = 0>

<CFLOOP QUERY="Course_seq">

<CFSET row = #Course_seq.CurrentRow#>

<CFQUERY NAME="relation" DATASOURCE="#CMS_SD#">
        SELECT *
        FROM moodle_relationships
        WHERE mrID=#Course_seq.mrID#
    </CFQUERY>

    <CFIF #row# LTE #numClasses#>
        <!--Change Classes-->
        <CFQUERY NAME="change" DATASOURCE="#CMS_SD#">
        UPDATE moodle_relationships
        SET mcID='#classes[row]#', active='Y'
        WHERE mrID=#relation.mrID#
        </CFQUERY>
    <CFELSEIF (#row# GT #numClasses#) AND (#row# LTE #numpreClasses#)>
        <!--Set to N-->
        <CFQUERY NAME="set" DATASOURCE="#CMS_SD#">
        UPDATE moodle_relationships
            SET active='N'
            WHERE mrID=#relation.mrID#
        </CFQUERY>
    </CFIF>
</CFLOOP>
```

Now the issue I am having is when the current sequence of classes exceeds the number of rows in the previous sequence. I need to somehow notice when this occurs and do an INSERT statement for the remaining rows.

For instance:

Original sequence - class 1, class 2, class 3
New sequence - class 1, class 2, class 3, class 4

Since my loop will only iterate three times it never considers the fourth index.

How can I fix this?

---

**EDIT**

I managed to fix this issue myself by creating CFSET count = 0, then count += 1 when an item is modified in the database. After that I created this code snippet.

```
<CFIF #count# LT #numClasses#>
<CFLOOP FROM="#count#" TO="#numClasses#" INDEX="i">
    <CFQUERY NAME="mrID" DATASOURCE="#CMS_SD#">
        SELECT MAX(mrID) AS MAXmrID
        FROM moodle_relationships
        WHERE mpID = #URL.id#
    </CFQUERY>
    <CFSET ID = #mrID.MAXmrID# - 1>
    <CFQUERY NAME="new" DATASOURCE="#CMS_SD#">
        INSERT INTO moodle_relationships (mpID, mcID, active, predecessor)
        VALUES ('#URL.id#', '#classes[i]#', 'Y', '#ID#')
    </CFQUERY>
</CFLOOP>
```

It works from what i see except a rogue bug where after updating the tables and going back to edit the course, sometimes I notice that one class has been changed to a different class, more specifically a class that already exists in the sequence creating a duplicate.

I am thinking it has to do with my comparison operators in the main loop where a consideration for a row is overlapping although i cant see where it is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One way is to delete all the existing records and enter a new set.

```
<cfscript>
    /* Count the number of classes before the edit */
    preclasses = listToArray(PREsectionOrder, ",");
    numpreClasses = ArrayLen(preclasses);

    /* Count the number of classes after edit */
    classes = listToArray(sectionOrder, ",");
    numClasses = ArrayLen(classes);
</cfscript>

<!--- Making sure we have a 'numeric' URL id --->
<CFPARAM name="URL.id" default="0" type="numeric" />

<CFSET courseId = URL.id />

<!--- Only continue if the courseId is not the default 0--->
<CFIF courseId neq 0>

    <!--- Delete the existing course and its combination classes --->
    <!--- Query checks for a specific course and class id --->
    <CFQUERY NAME="Course_seq" DATASOURCE="#CMS_SD#">
        DELETE 
          FROM moodle_relationships
         WHERE mpID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#courseId#" />
           AND mcID IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#PREsectionOrder#" list="true" separator=","/>)
    </CFQUERY>

    <!--- Create and Set the predecessor value to default 0--->
    <cfset predecessorValue = 0 />

    <!--- Loop over the array of new classId and Insert them--->
    <CFLOOP array="#classes#" index="newClass">

        <CFQUERY NAME="insertingNewCourse" DATASOURCE="#CMS_SD#">
            INSERT INTO moodle_relationships 
                    (mpID, mcID, active, predecessor)
            VALUES  (
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#courseId#" />,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#newClass#" />,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="Y" />,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#predecessorValue#" />
                    )
        </CFQUERY>

        <!--- The first one goes as zero. the next one shall be the just inserted classId --->
        <cfset predecessorValue = newClass />
    </CFLOOP>

</CFIF>
```

**CAUTION**: *Because, there is Delete involved, make sure you run this code on the test database.*

Comment: Hmm I don't know why I didn't think of deleting the rows first. I tried this code and its a lot less bulky than mine. I forgot to mention however that when a relationship no longer exists e.g. you remove a class, the relationship rows active value should be set to 'N'.

Comment: Glad that you have put this through test. For the flag to be set 'N', you can change the Delete Code to Update. Also, vote the answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: Perfect! I modified the query to flag to 'N' and it worked like a charm. Thanks again, glad to bring this project to a close, was the last detail to finish.